# How to disable kswapd0?

Tags: linux

I have already `swapoff -a` and set swampiness to 0, but when my linux server's memory becomes 60~70%, the kswapd0 pops on top of the `top` output, then the server becomes no response. Cannot even ssh.

What is kswapd0, and why kswapd0 cause my system freeze that I cannot even ssh?

How can I completely disable kswapd0?

Comment: Write a new memory manager and recompile the kernel with it? You are meddling with an intrinsic part of the OS, and it us designed to require some swap. Don't do that.